# Python - function calling exec() does not see variable

Tags: python, exec

I have following script that works well on it's own, but once I wrap it all into a function does not return data.
The command changes based on input data structure. This is an example of the command I want to feed into the exec():

```
cross_data=pd.crosstab(src_data['result'],[src_data['c1'],src_data['c2']],normalize='index')
```

This is my function I want to wrap the code in and call:

```py
    def calcct(file_path='src_data.csv', separator = ",", res_col = 'result'):    
        #define function

        src_data = csv_import(file_path, separator) #import data
        reorder_cols = reorder_columns(src_data, res_col) #work with data
        head_list=list(reorder_cols.columns.values) #get dataframe headers

        # create command based on headers and execute that. Should return dataframe called cross_data.
        exec(crosstabcmd(head_list)) 
        return cross_data
```

Results in:

```
NameError: name 'cross_data' is not defined
```

I cannot seem to find the correct syntax for calling exec inside a function.
I tried defining and passing the cross_data variable, but I just get an error it doesnt see pandas when I do that.

Or is there some better way? I need to compose the command of 2-x column names, count and names of columns are variable.

Comment: have You taken a look at what arguments `exec` takes? now I am not sure but I think there is something about scope so check that maybe.

Comment: We're missing some relevant parts of the code, can you provide a [mcve] ?

Answer (score 0):

### First up

You probably don't mean to be using `exec` - that's a pretty low-level functionality! There isn't really enough context to understand how to fix this yet. Could you write out (in your question) what the `crosstabcmd` function looks like?

### The error

```
NameError: name 'cross_data' is not defined
```

is because you've never defined a variable called `cross_data` in the scope of function `calcct`, i.e. you have never done `cross_data = "something"`.

### I'll give it a go

Assuming you have something like

```py
import pandas as pd

def crosstabcmd(head_list):
    # ? I can only guess what your crosstabcmd does, this won't work though
    return pd.crosstab(*head_list, normalize='index')
```

then the solution would look like:

```py
def calcct(file_path = 'src_data.csv', separator = ",", res_col = 'result'):
    src_data = csv_import(file_path, separator) #import data
    reorder_cols = reorder_columns(src_data, res_col) #work with data
    head_list=list(reorder_cols.columns.values) #get dataframe headers
    cross_data = crosstabcmd(head_list)
    return cross_data
```

Comment: Thank you for responding. the crosstabcmd takes argument as list of dataframe column names and using those pastes together a command.
So if the input list is 'result', 'c1', 'c2', the result it gives is this:
```
cross_data=pd.crosstab(src_data['result'],[src_data['c1'],src_data['c2']],normalize='index')
```
I do not know before running the script what will be the column names and how many I will get.

If I run the command outside the function it works and I can use the result inside variable cross_data, but I cannot access it once I put the code inside a function.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had main script which called a second script. I needed to use the "c" variable within the second script. Therefore I used **locals(),loc** as arguments for exec().

```
loc = {}
a = 10
b = 5
def abc(a,b):
    qwerty = "c = %d + %d"%(a,b)
    exec(qwerty, locals(), loc)
    c = loc['c']
    d = c+2
    print(d)

abc(a,b)
```